# ReactiveCocoa: How do you unit test a RACCommand?

Tags: ios, unit-testing, reactive-cocoa

In `MVVM pattern`, `ViewModel` give out a `RACCommand` and `View` bind a button with the `RACCommand`, but how to test the `RACCommand`?

I have two aspects that needs to be tested:

- under some conditions, the `RACCommand` should be enabled
- fire that command and see if the `ViewModel` does its job when the command fires

How to test these cases?

Answer (score 0):

I'm using [Kiwi](https://github.com/kiwi-bdd/Kiwi) for testing and it's pretty straightforward to use with `ReactiveCocoa`. In your case, [Kiwi's async testing](https://github.com/kiwi-bdd/Kiwi/wiki/Asynchronous-Testing) comes handy, for example using `shouldEventually` for expecting a value to change. E.g. a `view` to become hidden from the execution signal's side effect.

```
[[expectFutureValue(theValue(view.hidden)) shouldEventually] beYes];
```

Regarding the enabled signal, you are able to subscribe to that one as well. So you create a subscription block `beforeAll`:

```
void (^buttonEnabledBlock)(NSNumber *) = ^(NSNumber *enabled) {
         _blockEnabled = enabled.boolValue;
    };
```

Now subscribe it to the command's enabled signal in your test case:

```
[subject.myButtonCommand.enabled subscribeNext:buttonEnabledBlock];
```

Then you are able to `expectFutureValue` of `theValue(_blockEnabled)` to eventually `beYes` or `beNo`.

You are also able to `stub` the command's `signalBlock` with an additional category to the `RACCommand` interface and do some magic in need.